# check if image exists with fetch (function does not return response)

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I have the following function to check if an image (avatar) exists on the server. If so, the avatar is displayed. If not, a default avatar is displayed.

```
export const Avatar = props => {

    const userId = props.userId

    const size = props.size ? props.size : 25

    fetch(URL.Avatar + '/' + userId + '_avatar.jpg').then(res => {
        if (res.status === 404) {
            return (
                <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/default.jpg' }} style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    borderRadius: size / 2
                }} />                
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/' + userId + '_avatar.jpg' }} style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    borderRadius: size / 2
                }} />                
            )
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return (
            <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/default.jpg' }} style={{
                width: size,
                height: size,
                borderRadius: size / 2
            }} />                
        )
    })

}
```

However, this function does not work. I get the error "nothing was returned from render", because the function thinks a return-statement (at the end) is missing. However, when I put some console.logs in it, the fetch itself is working. The URLs are correct, because when I put a return at the end with an Image-component, it works.

Anyone knows what the problem could be? Has it anything to do with async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fetch** is async and will return later than you're expecting it to, because the code will continue to run while **fetch** is waiting for the response.

You can solve this by `awaiting` the **fetch** and making the function `async`

```
export const Avatar = async props => {

    const userId = props.userId

    const size = props.size ? props.size : 25

    return await fetch(URL.Avatar + '/' + userId + '_avatar.jpg').then(res => {
        if (res.status === 404) {
            return (
                <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/default.jpg' }} style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    borderRadius: size / 2
                }} />                
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/' + userId + '_avatar.jpg' }} style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    borderRadius: size / 2
                }} />                
            )
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return (
            <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/default.jpg' }} style={{
                width: size,
                height: size,
                borderRadius: size / 2
            }} />                
        )
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have an actual `return` statement for this function. I'm not sure what your request response looks like if the image doesn't exist, but what happens if you set the default outside of the `fetch`?

Something like this:

```js
export const Avatar = props => {

    const userId = props.userId

    const size = props.size ? props.size : 25

    fetch(URL.Avatar + '/' + userId + '_avatar.jpg').then(res => {
        if (res.status === 404) {
            return (
                <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/default.jpg' }} style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    borderRadius: size / 2
                }} />                
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/' + userId + '_avatar.jpg' }} style={{
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    borderRadius: size / 2
                }} />                
            )
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        // Handle actual errors here
    })

    return (
        <Image source={{uri: URL.Avatar + '/default.jpg' }} style={{
            width: size,
            height: size,
            borderRadius: size / 2
        }} />                
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to fetch the image yourself before using it, it's redundant. Instead, you can use the [`onError`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#onerror) function of the `Image` component to identify that the image failed to load. You can save the URL in the component state and change it according to the success/failure status (see the [`onLoad`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#onload) function to identify that the image was successfully loaded).

Alternatively, you can set a default image that will show while the image is loading via the [`defaultSource`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#defaultsource) prop to act as a placeholder.